# How to prove $\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i \times \bigcup_{i\in I}B_i = \bigcup_{i\in I}(A_i \times B_i)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can someone help me how to prove this? We haven't had an example in class how to prove this, so I don't even know where to begin.

$$\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i \times \bigcup_{i\in I}B_i = \bigcup_{i\in I}(A_i \times B_i)$$

Answer (score 2):

It's not true. Let $I=\{1,2\}$, $A_1 = B_1=\{1\}$ and $A_2=B_2=\{2\}$. Then
$$(A_1\cup A_2)\times (B_1\cup B_2) = \{1,2\} \times \{1,2\} = \{(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2)\}$$
but
$$(A_1 \times B_1) \cup (A_2 \times B_2) =( \{1\} \times \{1\})\cup (\{2\}\times \{2\})=\{(1,1),(2,2)\}.$$

It is true, however, if you change the right-hand side to:
$$\bigcup_{i \in I} \bigcup_{j \in I} (A_i \times B_j).$$
Prove this using inclusions in both directions. I.e., pick an element $x \in \bigcup_{i \in I }A_i \times \bigcup_{i \in I}B_i$ and show it is in $\bigcup_{i \in I} \bigcup_{j \in I} (A_i \times B_j)$. Then pick an element $x \in \bigcup_{i \in I} \bigcup_{j \in I} (A_i \times B_j)$ and show it is in $\bigcup_{i \in I }A_i \times \bigcup_{i \in I}B_i$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But if it would be $\bigcap_{i\in I}A_i \times \bigcap_{i\in I}B_i = \bigcap_{i\in I}(A_i \times B_i)$ it would be true, am I right?

Comment: Yes, that would be correct. Again it could be proved by showing inclusions in both directions.